# Why is docker swarm not picking up latest tags pushed to Google Container Registry?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-swarm, google-container-registry

I'm wondering if there's an issue with docker swarm and GCR or if GCR is experiencing some delays right now.

I pushed my newly tagged image to GCR, but it's changes are not available to the nodes on my cluster. They have pulled five other versions of the exact same image from GCR.

This is my push:

```
docker push gcr.io/me/myimage:0.0.5
The push refers to repository [gcr.io/me/myimage]
310bd8913b53: Layer already exists 
20d2e739cce3: Layer already exists 
328545f2b7b7: Layer already exists 
087a146ecf85: Layer already exists 
78da480ad576: Layer already exists 
7ff93b2699ab: Layer already exists 
f58cfeda9e5f: Layer already exists 
33aed7748ee3: Layer already exists 
0e0b4ee1c6dc: Layer already exists 
ff57bdb79ac8: Layer already exists 
6e5e20cbf4a7: Layer already exists 
86985c679800: Layer already exists 
8fad67424c4e: Layer already exists 
0.0.5: digest: sha256: ... size: 3053
```

And then trying to scale up to the new image shows:

```
$ docker service scale is_app=1
is_app scaled to 1
overall progress: 0 out of 1 tasks 
1/1: No such image: gcr.io/me/myimage:0.0.5
```

And if I recreate the stack and run `docker service ps --no-trunc` on myimage service, I get...

```
docker service ps is_app --no-trunc
ID                          NAME                IMAGE                          NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE                     ERROR                                           PORTS
6accpgxjdfq936vsoco8qa9cc   is_app.1            gcr.io/me/myimage:0.1.0   app-swarm-w1        Ready               Rejected less than a second ago   "No such image: gcr.io/me/myimage:0.1.0"   
e69xzn1m9vp6kcj0m9gy95fvd    \_ is_app.1        gcr.io/me/myimage:0.1.0   app-swarm-m0        Shutdown            Rejected 20 seconds ago           "No such image: gcr.io/me/myimage:0.1.0"   
gojagqi0vjh5y088xgn99xbg9    \_ is_app.1        gcr.io/me/myimage:0.1.0   app-swarm-m0        Shutdown            Rejected 25 seconds ago           "No such image: gcr.io/me/myimage:0.1.0"   
ya3f0g8lji4522em0ge78gfg9    \_ is_app.1        gcr.io/me/myimage:0.1.0   app-swarm-m0        Shutdown            Rejected 30 seconds ago           "No such image: gcr.io/me/myimage:0.1.0"   
les1emnyzvghzjlxa5huysa9n    \_ is_app.1        gcr.io/me/myimage:0.1.0   app-swarm-m0        Shutdown            Rejected 36 seconds ago           "No such image: gcr.io/me/myimage:0.1.0"
```

Yet, if I run a `docker-machine ssh` into the machine and run `gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/me/myimage:0.0.5`, it shows:

```
DIGEST        TAGS   TIMESTAMP
007300edd521  0.0.5  2018-04-26T05:42:36
46a297a45f61  0.0.4  2018-04-26T00:31:35
ff8160e40214  0.0.3  2018-04-26T00:22:32
ec4517dbae67  0.0.2  2018-04-25T23:09:53
b9f3400a298c  0.0.1  2018-04-25T20:02:55
0244b39f532e  0      2018-04-24T20:01:51
```

So it exists. How long does it take to propagate for docker swarm to pick it up? Is this normal? Is there some workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I forgot to pass `--with-registry-auth` to `docker stack deploy` which affects the connection to GCR. This fixed the issue.